# Swift cast Any to RangeExpression

Tags: swift, casting

I have a dictionary that `[String:Any]` and need to be able to check if Any is a RangeExpression. I want to be able to pass in any type of range ,ClosedRange, Range... (1..2, 1..<5)

```
if let range = options["Range"] as? RangeExpression {

}
```

I get an error `Protocol 'RangeExpression' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Is this possible? Or a different approach I should be using?

Comment: Why are you storing ranges in a `[String:Any]`?

Comment: Where does the `[String: Any]` come from? Did you make it? Can you use something else instead?

Comment: I am guessing you are going to use those ranges to index a collection, right?

Comment: The `options` dictionary is parameter passed into a function.

Comment: I meant to ask, where does the values in the dictionary come from? Do you pass them in yourself as well, in some other parts of the code? Or does the dictionary values come from somewhere where you have no control over? You still haven't responded my second question.

Comment: @Sweeper I pass them in myself. I am trying to check status codes coming back from an HTTP response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment

> I am trying to check status codes coming back from an HTTP response

I will assume that at some later parts of your code, you are going to do something like:

```
if range.contains(statusCode) {
    // blah blah blah
}
```

if that's all you need (i.e. not using the range to index an array), you can try to create an erased `AnyRange` type like this:

```
struct AnyRange {
    let contains: (Int) -> Bool

    init<T: RangeExpression>(_ range: T) where T.Bound == Int {
        contains = range.contains
    }
}
```

When you are putting in values into your dictionary, do something like this:

```
let options: [String: Any] = ["Range": AnyRange(200..<300)]
```

And then you can cast every range to `AnyRange`:

```
if let range = options["Range"] as? AnyRange {
    if range.contains(statusCode) {
        // blah blah blah
    }
}
```

---

From the looks of it, you seem to be storing things of different types in the same dictionary. This is a good opportunity to create a struct instead:

```
struct Options {
    let range: AnyRange

    // put other stuff you want to store here...
}
```

This way, you don't need the casting. Everything is strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using RangeExpression as a generic constraint?
E.g.:

```
func takeRange<T: RangeExpression>(with dict: [String: T]) {
  if let range = dict.first?.value {
     print(range)
  }
}
```

`Range` could then be further used anywhere where a `RangeExpression` is required.